# PostSharp - Installation Process Failed to Install Compiled Images. Process failed with Code 4

Tags: postsharp

I have just updated the PostSharp to PostSharp 3.1 [3.1.41.0, 32 bit, CLR 4.5, Release] and am getting this error. How to fix this?

[image: PostSharp Error]

Comment: Got same problem here!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed in version 3.1.42: [PostSharp failed with code: 4](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/2046-postsharp-failed-with-code-4)